# Activate auto scroll Jquery function only on some divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have this code taken from [a tutorial](https://techglimpse.com/divi-full-page-section-scroll-next-section/) :

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).on( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function( event ) {
 if ( ( $( '.et_pb_side_nav' ).length === 0 ) || $( 'html, body' ).is( ':animated' ) ) return;
event.preventDefault();
 var direction = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
var $position = $( '.et_pb_side_nav' ).find( '.active' );
var $target;
if( direction < 0 ) {
$target = $( $position ).parent().next();
} else {
$target = $( $position ).parent().prev();
}
if ( $( $target.length ) !== 0 ) {
$( $target ).children( 'a' ).trigger( "click" );
}
} );
 } )( jQuery );
```

I'm trying to activate this function only if the Div visible on screen has a specific class. The objective is to make sure it only auto scrolls on some sections of the page and not others. So if the Div visible has the class it activates the function and scrolls to the next, but if it doesn't, it scrolls normally.
Any idea how I could do this ?

I tried this :

```
<script>
if ( $("div").hasClass("autoscroll") {
 ( function( $ ) {
 $( document ).on( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function( event ) {
if ( ( $( '.et_pb_side_nav' ).length === 0 ) || $( 'html, body' ).is( ':animated' ) ) return;
event.preventDefault();
 var direction = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
 var $position = $( '.et_pb_side_nav' ).find( '.active' );
var $target;
if( direction < 0 ) {
$target = $( $position ).parent().next();
} else {
 $target = $( $position ).parent().prev();
}
if ( $( $target.length ) !== 0 ) {
$( $target ).children( 'a' ).trigger( "click" );
}
} );
} )( jQuery );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

```
$('.autoscroll').each(function() { //foreach element with a class of autoscroll. 
  //your code here
});
```